# RadioButtons in RadioGroup arent working as intended

Tags: android

I have a `RadioGroup` with two `RadioButton`'s:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/main_radiogroup_lock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/main_layout_lock_dummy"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/main_radiobutton_lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_radiobutton_lock"
        android:button="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/main_radiobutton_unlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="230dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_radiobutton_unlock"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I initialize the `RadioButton`'s and set an `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
...
this.radioButtonLock = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.main_radiobutton_lock);
this.radioButtonLock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
this.radioButtonUnlock = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.main_radiobutton_unlock);
this.radioButtonUnlock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
...

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.main_radiobutton_lock) {
        Log.v("MainFragment", "Lock");

        this.imageButtonLanguage.setEnabled(false);
        this.buttonOpen.setEnabled(false);
        this.buttonAutomatic.setEnabled(false);
        this.buttonClose.setEnabled(false);
        this.buttonFog.setEnabled(false);
        this.checkBoxRed.setEnabled(false);
        this.checkBoxGreen.setEnabled(false);
        this.checkBoxBlue.setEnabled(false);

        return;
    } else if(view.getId() == R.id.main_radiobutton_unlock) {
        Log.v("MainFragment", "Unlock");

        this.imageButtonLanguage.setEnabled(true);
        this.buttonOpen.setEnabled(true);
        this.buttonAutomatic.setEnabled(true);
        this.buttonClose.setEnabled(true);
        this.buttonFog.setEnabled(true);
        this.checkBoxRed.setEnabled(true);
        this.checkBoxGreen.setEnabled(true);
        this.checkBoxBlue.setEnabled(true);

        return;
    }
}
```

So when i now start the app my `radioButtonUnlock` is checked. When i know chec the `radioButtonLock` nothing happens and no log output but the checked image is set so the checking is working. When i after that again check the `radioButtonUnlock` the following output appears:

```
02-04 09:59:31.355: V/MainFragment(533): Lock
02-04 09:59:31.355: V/MainFragment(533): Unlock
```

So both `RadioButton`'s are fired. After that everytime i press one of the `RadioButton`'s all events are fired. After pressing the `radioButtonLock` the following happens:

```
02-04 09:59:32.850: V/MainFragment(533): Unlock
02-04 09:59:32.850: V/MainFragment(533): Lock
```

Whats the point of that? I set different ID's so why are always both `RadioButtons`'s fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope will work -

1)set check change listener to radio group

```
RedioGroup rg =(RadioGroup)findviewByid(R.id.main_radiogroup_lock);
rg.setcheckchangedlistener(true);
```

2)handle on check change listener event

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(checkedId){

    case R.id.rdb1:
        radio_selected = R.id.rdb1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    case R.id.rdb2:
        radio_selected = R.id.rdb2;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"second",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```